# É possivel usar node.js no cpanel?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cpanel

Pretendo fazer tanto um aplicativo quanto um site se comunicarem com meu banco de dados através do *node.js*. Gostaria de saber se qualquer *host* como os mais simples que possuem *cpanel*(godaddy) tem suporte ao *node.js* ou *mongoDB*.

Answer (score 0):

Tem sim, mas voce precisa solicitar que eles instalem o node.js, pois o mariaDB por padrão já vem, eis uma empresa que faz isso, ja usei nela

https://www.argohost.net/